# jQuery Validation methods for zip code

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate zip codes in a form field. This method I am applying to the zipcode object will validate the form correctly when the user types in too many or too few, but if they do nothing at all then the placeholder text, "12345", in the form allows the user to pass the validation successfully. So I am trying to add to this code here something like "or == "12345" then return false".  Any ideas on how?

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('zipcode', function(value, element) {

      return this.optional(element) || !!value.trim().match(/^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$/) || !!value == "12345";

    }, 'Invalid zip code');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want:

```
return this.optional(element) || 
    (/^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$/.test(value.trim()) && value !== "12345");
```

or a little more robustly if you are in fact using the `placeholder` attribute:

```
return this.optional(element) || 
    (/^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$/.test(value.trim()) && 
           value !== $(element).attr('placeholder'));
```

I've also replaced `match` with [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test), which you should use if you just want to know if a string matches a RegExp.